# Get all employees that do not have vouchers on a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

Having an one to many relationship between the tables employees and vouchers with the following schema definition:

```
employees
    - id
    - full_name

vouchers
    - id
    - employee_id
    - date
```

I need to get all employees that do not have vouchers on a specific date.

Right now what I am doing in the back-end code is first get all employee list and then all employees who has vouchers an a specific date. And finally subtract both employees list. In this way i get the difference between both employees list.

This is the logic I am using in grails framework

```
private List<Employee> getEmployeeListInDate(final Date date) {
    List<Employee> employeeList = employeeService.list()
    List<Employee> employeeListInDate = employeeService.listInDate(date)

    employeeList - employeeListInDate
}
```

This works. But I would like to know how can I implement this logic using sql query? I Created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23653b/2) to facilitate your collaboration.

Thanks for your time

Comment: +1 for the fiddle, as well as for trying to do this in your database. Writing a single query/view/SP to get your data, instead of writing additional code to do what an RDBMS is optimized to do (as well as all the overhead of either querying for data that you won't end up using, or making multiple queries when a simple join would have sufficed) is important for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `not exists` works well. For completeness, I'll mention that you can also use an outer join, like this:

```
select 
  e.*
from 
  employees e
  left outer join vouchers v
    on (e.id=v.employee_id and v.date = {date here})
where
  v.id is null
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23653b/8)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `not exists`.

```
select * 
from employees e
where not exists (select 1 from vouchers v where v.employee_id=e.id 
                  and v.date = --put a date in here
                 )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use left or right outer join such as this:

```
select * from employees
left join vouchers on employees.id=vouchers.emp_id and date='2017-10-11'
where vouchers.id is null
```

Basically what you are looking for is to get this set

[image: LEFT JOIN]

Comment: Right now the query won't work, because your `where` clause is looking for both the id being null, while having an actual date value in the date column. You can think of `on` as being like a `where` clause for the table you are joining in, and then the actual `where` clause as a filter for the resulting rows from your join.